# ROS node on container cannot publish to roscore on physical hardware

Tags: ros

I have roscore running on a VM (network bridged)hardware.
I have another node running inside a docker container.

On the master, I am publishing to a topic, and can subscribe to that topic.
On the node, I am publishing to a topic.  Neither the node nor the master can see the data published, even though the topic shows in the list.

On the node I can subscribe to topics published on the master.

What I have done:
On each machine I have set ROS_IP to the machine's IP address.
On the node (container) I am running this with `--net host` so I have set ROS_IP to the host's physical IP address.

I have edited each hosts `/etc/hosts` file and added each other's host/IP combination.

core:

```
rostopic pub /VM std_msgs/String "From the VM" -r 2
```

Also on the core:

```
$ rostopic echo /VM
data: "From the VM"
```

On the node:

```
rostopic pub /PC std_msgs/String "PC container" -r 2
```

Also on the node:

```
rostopic echo /PC
```

Nothing ever received.
On the node:

```
$ rostopic echo /VM
data: "From the VM"
```

Finally, on the VM, nothing is received:

```
$ rostopic echo /PC
```

This leads me to believe that the node is not publishing. But I am not sure how to troubleshoot this further.

Answer (score 0):

When working in containers discovery can be a problem, in particular FastRTPS the default DDS is challenging to get to work with containers. When I am using containers I usually use CycloneDDS with `--net=host` that you're already doing.

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ros-$DISTRO-rmw-cyclonedds-cpp && export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_cyclonedds_cpp`

---

I've put together [a PR for rocker](https://github.com/osrf/rocker/pull/268) as a proof of concept how to make this slightly easier to do in docker.

With that branch of rocker I can use either
`rocker --rmw fastrtps --net=host -- osrf/ros:iron-desktop ros2 run examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher publisher_member_function` or `rocker --rmw cyclonedds --net=host -- osrf/ros:iron-desktop ros2 run examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher publisher_member_function`

With `rocker --rmw cyclonedds --net=host -- osrf/ros:iron-desktop ros2 run examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber subscriber_member_function` as the subscriber in a separate container.

Comment: I was using Docker on Windows.  This added an extra challenge because the IP address the container was getting was related the Hyper-V network stack. Ultimately, I don't think that layering is possible.  I threw together a VM instead.

Comment: Oh, on Windows I think that Docker is in a VM itself potentially on a separate network.

Comment: Yup, it sure is!  I resolved this by building a VM instead.  I think (but not confirmed) ROS2 has fixed some of these nuances.  I'll try it at some point, but this legacy program uses ROS1.